# Finding a natural number in C#

Tags: c#

I wrote code, That should tell what is the minil value of P that will make the whole sqrt a natural number.
The problem is that every time it gets to the part of P=K, the loop stops and says that is the same value.
for example: for the number 4 it works perfectly, but for 5 it says they are equal, but the sqrt of 45 is not a natural number

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int k, p = 0;
            double final;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value of K ");
            k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            final = System.Math.Sqrt(4 * k + System.Math.Pow(p, 2));
            while (final - (int)(final) != 0&&p!=k)
            {
                final = System.Math.Sqrt(4 * k + System.Math.Pow(p, 2));
                p++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("k is {0}, and P is {1}", k, p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code, in whatever language it is written will not do what you think it *has* to do until you *make* it do that.

Comment: Code is written by you, if it doesn't work....

Comment: more like error on layer 8

Comment: this is an interesting way of seeing if a number has decimals ; `final - (int)(final) != 0`, are you sure this always works like you intend it?

Comment: Look guys, i agree that the wording is less than brilliant but as far as i'm concerned this is a valid question. why the downvotes?

Comment: Nobody (should be) posting code on here that works correctly. And you've put C# (correctly) as a tag. You've completely wasted your opportunity to put anything descriptive in the title.

Comment: Nobody (should be) posting code on here that works correctly? oh my god, what have i been doing all this time? 0_0

Comment: Lets give **some** valuable comments at least... look at your loop condition `(final - (int)(final) != 0 && p!=k)`. It says that the loop will continue while `[unimportant rounding condition] AND [P doesn't equal K]`. So the loop stops for `P == K` and you get the result you don't want.

Comment: @TimothyGroote I think Damiens comment was implicitely targeted at questions, not answers :D still I wouldn't necessarily agree to it.

Comment: It might help here if you explained what it is you are trying to achieve with your code. At the moment you seem to want us to figure out what you are trying to do from code that doesn't yet do what you want it to do. Unless someone happens by that recognises the formula and can figure out your mistake, you'll not get a meaningful answer.

Comment: i still think i'm missing something here ; you say *that every time it gets to the part of P=K* ; i see no `P=K`, nor do i see a `P==K`, which i would sooner expect since `P=K` would probably ruin what you are trying to achieve. i don't get what exactly you are asking, or what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Note: It's not explicitely stated in the question, but I assume `K` to be a natural number (not negative!), otherwise the solution becomes more complex.

Lets re-examine the lower and upper bounds of the problem:

The lower bound is pretty trivial: `Q² == 4K` and thus, `P == 0`

The upper bound is given by `Q² == (K+1)² == 4K + (K-1)²`, so `P == K-1` (assumung `K > 1`, since the cases of `K == 0` and `K == 1` are trivial and have upper bound equal to lower bound).

This means, the expectation to find a valid `P` before `P == K` (or in case of `K == 0`, then `P == 0`) is a valid one (which was not that obvious to me when first looking at the question).

So lets move on to the question, why your code does not find the result in the range `[0, K-1]`.

Basically, the reason is you compute a sub-result `final` and then you change `p` before testing the result. So, whenever you find a valid result `final`, you wrongly print the value `p+1` as your result.

The solution: change the order of statements in your loop:

```
while (final - (int)(final) != 0&&p!=k)
{
    p++;
    final = System.Math.Sqrt(4 * k + System.Math.Pow(p, 2));
}
```